# How to update UIView in swift

Tags: swift, swift2, uiswitch

I have a `UISwitch` in a  view. I have a anther thread to detect a value A.
I want to update view to set `UISwitch` be true or false depend on value A which is true or false.

How can I update UIView to change `UISwitch` in real time? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    self.switchControl.on = aValue
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but How to do real time?

Comment: iOS and OS X does not provide facility for thread interruption in the middle and performing arbitrary work on it. Main thread has `Run loop` attached which wakes the thread up once there are events to process, like UI interactions, timers, or arbitrary work execution tasks. The only option here is to perform task synchronously or async-ly. If you are interested in synchronous variant you can use `dispatch_sync`. In this case you worker thread will be blocked till the completion of the block where you update the switch. Does it help?